# Make tkinter GUI window on top over omxplayer HDMI video screen

Tags: python, tkinter, omxplayer

I have a project of IOT where i am using `python-3.6` on raspberry pi zero and `tkinter` for GUI.

Pi is always playing video on a TV with direct HDMI (`omxplayer`).

**Problem:**
I need to open a `tkinter` GUI window to connect wifi but GUI display index is below than the `omxplayer` screen.

**What i want**
I want to display GUI on top over omxplayer screen to connect wi-fi.

**I have tried:**

```
1 root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1) 
  #Not working wm is not defined

2 root.overridedirect(1)
  root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
  #Window is jumping on top of every other applications but not over omxplayer.

3 root.attributes("-topmost", 1)
  #Window is jumping on top of every other applications but not over omxplayer.

4 root.lift()
  #Not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution although its not a valid solution.
**What i did ?**
Instead of making `tkinter GUI` on top i just bind hot key `ctrl+j` to hide `omxplayer` screen and `ctrl+k` to show screen.

```
from omxplayer.player import OMXPlayer
import omxplayer.keys
import codecs
from pynput import keyboard
import threading

xpress = False

# The key combination to check
COMBINATIONS = [
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='j')},
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='J')},
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='k')},
    {keyboard.Key.ctrl, keyboard.KeyCode(char='K')}
]

# The currently active modifiers
current = set()

def execute(key):
    keys = str(key).replace("'", "")
    print ("Do Something", keys)

    if keys == 'j':
        global xpress
        xpress = True
        print(xpress)
    else:
        xpress = False
        print(xpress)

def on_press(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.add(key)
        if any(all(k in current for k in COMBO) for COMBO in COMBINATIONS):
            execute(key)

def on_release(key):
    if any([key in COMBO for COMBO in COMBINATIONS]):
        current.remove(key)

def ThKeyboad():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=ThKeyboad, args=[])
t1.start()

#OMXPlayer Code

player = OMXPlayer('/home/pi/outhum/video/default.mp4', dbus_name='org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.omxplayer2')

if xpress:
    player.hide_video()
else:
    player.show_video()
a = player.duration()
time.sleep(a)
player.quit()
```

Comment: Please note that player is will hide on next omxplayer instance and same for unhiding.